# Display one div at a time with multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, toggle

Using Foundation 6 as my framework, I wanted to implement a fading effect between two `divs` when a button is pressed.

The effect I'm trying to do is when `button1` is clicked, `div2` will hide and fade out (if visible) and `div1` will show and fade in, and vice versa.

Here is my Javascript code:

```
var $button1 = $('#button1');
var $button2 = $('#button2');

var $div1 = $('#div1');
var $div2 = $('#div2');

$button1.click(function() {
  if ($div2.is(':visible')) {
    MotionUI.animateOut($div2, 'fadeOut');
    MotionUI.animateIn($div1, 'fadeIn');
  }
  else {
    $div1.show();
  }
});

$button2.click(function() {
  if ($div1.is(':visible')) {
    MotionUI.animateOut($div1, 'fadeOut');
    MotionUI.animateIn($div2, 'fadeIn');
  }
  else {
    $div2.show();
  }
});
```

I have gotten `div1` and `div2` to fade in/out between the two with one button, but I can't seem to get it to work when using multiple buttons.

Comment: I'm unsure what you're trying to accomplish. Pressing either button will toggle the divs?

Comment: What are `$listButton` and `$gridButton`, and you don't seem to be using `$button1` and `$button2`. So are listButton and gridButton supposed to be button1 and button2? And what doesn't work? Do neither of the divs hide, does only 1 hide

Comment: Also, you're doing a lot of logic you don't need to do. jQuery's toggle() method will do all the logic for you. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/f1dshffs/1/

Comment: Thanks @Kolby it worked! How do I remove the jump that occurs on click?

Comment: @Patrick Evnas Oops I changed $listButton and $gridButton to $button1 and $button2 for explanation purposes but forgot to change the code at the bottom, fixed! My problem with the code was that neither of the divs hide (I have div1 start off as visible)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simple way to toggle `display:none` using jQuery's `toggle()` methods. I used fadeToggle since you mentioned wanting a fade, but you could use toggle and set a css3 transition instead.

Keeping the code super simple - to match what you have - this is how you would do it:
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f1dshffs/2/

```
var $button1 = $('#button1');
var $button2 = $('#button2');

var $div1 = $('#div1');
var $div2 = $('#div2');


var toggleDivs = function(){
    $div1.fadeToggle();
    $div2.fadeToggle();
};

$button1.click(toggleDivs);
$button2.click(toggleDivs);
```

Now there's some things you could do to optimize your code a little bit by selecting by a class instead of an id, and then adding only 1 event to the array of objects.

It reduces the code down to: Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f1dshffs/3/

```
var buttons = $('.button');
var divs = $('.div');

var toggleDivs = function(){
    divs.fadeToggle();
};

buttons.click(toggleDivs);
```